# Proof for the following stochastic ordering

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2$ be iid random variables and $X$ be another random variable each with support $[0,\infty)$. Let $c$ be the realization of $X$. How do i prove the following relation if true,

$P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2) \geq P(X_1 \ge c | X_1 < X_2)$

The relation feels intuitively true, but i am unable to prove it. This is not a homework question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is quite right. In fact, you have the inequalities
$$
P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2) \geq P(X_1 \geq c) \geq P(X_1 \ge c | X_1 < X_2),
$$
because the information that $X_1>X_2$ ($X_1$ is "big") can only increase the probability in the middle while the information that $X_1<X_2$ ($X_1$ is "small") can only decrease it.

In order to prove your inequality it is meaningful to consider the following two cases:

1. If $X_2>c$ then the left probability becomes
   $$
   P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2)
   =
   \frac{P(X_1 \geq c , X_1 > X_2)}{P(X_1 > X_2)}
   =
   \frac{P(X_1 > X_2)}{P(X_1 > X_2)}
   =
   1,
   $$
   proving the inequality (the right probability can not exceed $1$).
2. If $X_2\le c$ then the right probability becomes
   $$
   P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 < X_2)
   =
   \frac{P(X_1 \geq c , X_1 < X_2)}{P(X_1 < X_2)}
   =
   0,
   $$
   also proving the inequality.

Now, an analysis by cases might be not satisfactory for probabilistic purposes (though it is accurate). If you want to make the argument rigorous, you use the upper observations together with the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), where you condition additionally on the cases $X_2\le c$ and $X_2>c$:
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2)
&=
P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2, X_2\le c)P(X_2\le c) + P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 > X_2,X_2> c)P(X_2 > c)
\\
&\geq
P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 < X_2, X_2\le c)P(X_2\le c) + P(X_1 \geq c | X_1 < X_2,X_2> c)P(X_2 > c)
\\
&=
P(X_1 \ge c | X_1 < X_2),
\end{align*}
where the inequality follows from the above observation.